# JSF / PrimeFaces compatibility with HTML5 Storage methods

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, local-storage, sessionstorage

Do JSF / PrimeFaces support well HTML5 Storage methods (sessionStorage / localStorage)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out the box. But you can just wrap the necessary HTML/JS code in custom JSF components. One of our previous interns have done that. You can find it in [this Google Code repository](https://code.google.com/p/html5-in-jsf-experiments/). Check the [POC-SessionStorage](https://code.google.com/p/html5-in-jsf-experiments/source/browse/#hg/POC-SessionStorage) part for the source code. You can find a writeup in [this thesis](http://jdevelopment.nl/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2012/07/markvandertol_thesis3.pdf).

To the point, it's merely a matter of generating the right HTML/JS code and hooking on JSF ajax events.