# Set values from localstorage to outputtext components inside a primefaces dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, local-storage

I want to set values from the localstorage value to an outputtext component in primefaces dialog.
The dialog is

```
    <p:commandButton id="clickBtn" value="Click to display the Dialog"/>

    <p:dialog id="eventDetailDialog" widgetVar="eventDialog"
        header="Service Details>
        <div>
            <h:form id="topForm" prependId="false">
                <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails1">
                    <h:outputText value="Assigned Employee "/>
                    <h:outputLabel value=":"/>
                    <h:outputText id="assignedEmpId" value="#{myBean.employee}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </p:dialog>
```

The generated html is

```
<td class="labelClass">Assigned Employee </td>
<td class="colnClass"><label>:</label></td>
<td class="valueClass"><span id="assignedEmpId"></span></td>
```

On button click

```
document.getElementById('assignedEmpId').innerHtml = localStorage.myDataEmp;
eventDialog.show();
```

But the value from locastorage is not being set to the component.
What should i do to set the localStorage value to a jsf / primefaces component?
Using jsf 2.1 and primefaces 4.0.

Also did a sample in w3schools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="clickBtn" value="Click Here"/>
Assigned Employee 
<span id="assignedEmpId"></span>

<script>

    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickBtn").click(function(){

   document.getElementById("assignedEmpId").innerHTML = localStorage.lastname;

    }); 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but same not working with JSF. Why?

Comment: I don't see any component with `assignedEmpId` id in your facelet.

Comment: soory my mistake .. i have corrected the code in the question.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320379/jsf-primefaces-compatibility-with-html5-storage-methods. I have search for how to have access to localStorage and I found a mention about such feature at balusc.blogspot.ro/2012/06/omnifaces-10-is-released.html, but I don't know if it's implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the answer. :)

change

```
document.getElementById('assignedEmpId').innerHtml = localStorage.myDataEmp;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('assignedEmpId').innerHTML = localStorage.myDataEmp;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<p:commandButton value="Click to display the Dialog"
                 oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()"
                 update="eventDetailDialog"  />
```